# Can I use "When you are placed in difficult situation" interchangeably with "When you are put in difficult situation"?

Tags: verbs, active-vs-passive

Can I say

> When you are put in difficult situation

instead of

> When you are placed in difficult situation

Are these interchangeable?

Comment: Hi Mohamed, you can make your questions better by telling us what you did (if anything) to try to answer them - for example, Google searches, looking the words up in a dictionary, etc. Otherwise, your questions might get down-voted or closed by moderators on this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit (thanks Mari-Lou A for pointing out that I glossed over the missing article):

Both are good if you add the article "a"
- When (you are) placed/put in a difficult situation.

You could also say "when faced with a difficult situation" or "when facing a difficult situation" (though these do not have the sense that someone caused it)

Comment: You added the much needed indefinite article "a", in "...[with] **a** difficult situation"

Comment: thanks @Mari-LouA - I totally missed the missing article